# How to append a number to a txt file after specific index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, append

I am beginner in Python and I have question if anybody can help please.

I have txt file. It has structure like is

-0.368242,-0.256205,-0.893732,2.27449e-17, -0.346157,-0.349505,-0.870645,1.21266e-17, -0.239658,0.461163,-0.854338,7.31435e-19,-0.21521,-0.21521,-0.213487, -0.213487,-0.952947,-4.74783e-19

all data type in the file is string.
I need to append to it some data which is coming from function.
This data type is numpynd array. The data is like this

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 671 122 1 39 ...]
```

I would like to append this array after every 4th element in the file.

Example:

```
-0.368242,-0.256205,-0.893732,2.27449e-17,[ 1 2 3 4 5 671 122 1 39 ...], 
-0.346157,-0.349505,-0.870645,1.21266e-17,[ 1344 26 73 84 5 671
122 1 39 ...]
```

The new array data is changing with time, it is a data coming for like 1 minute, so the first data comes and to be added after 4th element, and the second data will come and will be appended after the next series of elements

example

```
data 1= [1 2 3 4]
data 2 = [5 6 7 88]
```

output should be in the file like :

```
-0.368242,-0.256205,-0.893732,2.27449e-17,[1 2 3 4], 
-0.346157,-0.349505,-0.870645,1.21266e-17,[5 6 7 88]
```

I tried this but never had good results.

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
   tmp = line.strip().split(",")
   values = [float(v) for v in tmp]  # CONVERTING THE VALUES TO FLOAT
   insertation = np.insert(f, slice(0, None, 4), my_new_data)
   f.write(','.join(str(v) for v in insertation.flat) + '\n')
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks:)

Update: the input file was created from this function

```
    f = open("test_desc2.txt", "w")  # Erases the file content.
    f.close()
       

>  `HERE TRINGULATE FUNCTION EXISTS.`

    f = open("test.txt", "a")
    f.write(','.join(str(v) for v in self.tringulate.T.flat) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append an output to a txt file after every 4th element in this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62821021/how-to-append-an-output-to-a-txt-file-after-every-4th-element-in-this-file)

Comment: @Ehsan No, It doesn't  Thanks for your recommendation

Comment: @Ehsan I see you wrote comments in the other thread. I tried it but not very useful for my case. Any advice please?

Comment: So your input txt file has line breaks in the middle of the data items?

Comment: @alaniwi If I understand you correctly, It should have yes. I will update the post now to show how the input file was made.

Comment: @Timon I am referring to a number like `2.27449e-17` being split across two lines. Either you are having to cope with a very ill-formed input file, or it is just a formatting error in the question. UPDATE - having now seen how your input file is generated, there is no reason why it would do that (i.e. it is just a formatting error in the question) - please can you fix that? See near the start of the question.

Comment: @alaniwi I am not sure if I understand you much:) What is exactly wrong near the start of the question?

Comment: @alaniwi Update: Done, Do you have any advice for my problem?

Comment: @Timon I am not understanding exactly what you are trying, but the first argument to `np.insert` is meant to be an array, and you are giving it a file object.

Comment: @alaniwi Ok, let's say I want to append [1 2 3 4] to the input txt file after every 4th element in the file (Index[3]) as python starts from 0. How would the algorithm/function/code look like? Thanks

Comment: I mean after every 4th element , like after every 4th and then 8th and then 12th ,etc.

Comment: Seems to me that `values` is just a list, and maybe you want to insert directly into that list rather than using numpy - lists have an `insert` method.

Comment: @alaniwi great, but how to insert in every 4th element. That's the tricky part for me. Sorry I am still beginner:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, you can not use *Numpy* to perform your task.
The reason is that *Numpy* arrays have each element of just the same type,
whereas your list, at least after the insertion, contains a mixture of
*float*s and (nested) lists.

So I came up with a solution how to insert your sequence of
lists into a **plain** *pythonic* list.

I left out reading your list from a text file (at the start) and
writing it back into this file (at the end).

Assume that your source variables are as follows:

1. Source list (to insert into):

   ```
    a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
   ```
2. The sequences to insert:

   ```
    seqToIns = [[51.0, 52.0], [71.0, 72.0]]
   ```
3. The step between consecutive insertion points:

   ```
    step = 4
   ```

To circumvent the problem of "moving indices" (after each insert),
the idea is to insert your sequences in a **reversed** order.
To iterate over them you can use `seqToIns[::-1]`.

To generate (also reversed) list of target indices, you can use
`range(len(seqToIns) * step, 0, -step)`.

So the task boils down calling *insert* in a loop, based on "zipped"
results of both above expressions:

```
for ind, seq in zip(range(len(seqToIns) * step, 0, -step), seqToIns[::-1]):
    a.insert(ind, seq)
```

When you print your list again, you will get:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, [51.0, 52.0], 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, [71.0, 72.0], 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried that but it is appending the list data 1= [1 2 3 4] ( Which needs to be appended) to the input txt file not in the correct order. It is appending it like that = [89.96 23.6 0.74 0.923 1 0.2 0.5 0.8 0.4 2 0.23 0.524 0.2155 0.225 4 etc] It is basically appending EACH element of the data1 to the list separately . I want to append all data 1 after the 4th element and then data 2 after the 8th element, etc.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your data. Run my code on **my** data and check that the result is correct. At respective points there are inserted **lists**, without flattetning them.